# Swift pagination with JSON

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to get new data while scrolling down and append the new data to previous ones. I have tried to get it with page number but when I scroll down, next page's data loaded however the previous ones are gone. What should I do ?

```
func parse(json: Data){
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let jsonMovies = try? decoder.decode(Movies.self, from: json){
        movies = jsonMovies.results
        
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
    }
}

func getData() {
    let urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=58ea4fe48390e0d2e32f6d608a6e7b47&language=en-US&page=\(currentPage)"
    
    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            parse(json: data)
            
        }
    }
    
}

// This is the function that increments page number and calls the API function
func loadNewItemsFrom(currentPage: Int){
    self.currentPage += 1
    getData()
    
    collectionView.reloadData()
  
}


override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

    if offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.size.height {
        /* increment page index to load new data set from */
        
        /* call API to load data from next page or just add dummy data to your datasource */
        /* Needs to be implemented */
        loadNewItemsFrom(currentPage: currentPage)

        /* reload tableview with new data */
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're just doing `movies = jsonMovies.results` which wipes out what previous existed in `movies` and sets it to the new results. Instead, you'll probably want to append the results to the `movies` array (something like `movies.append(contentsOf: jsonMovies.results)`)

Eventually, you'll want more robust logic for testing whether or not those results truly belong at the end, such as if API responses come back out-of-order.

Speaking of API responses, you'll want to look into using something like a `URLSession` for loading your data instead of `Data(contentsOf: url)` which will load data synchronously and be a plague on your scrolling performance. There's plenty of good information here on SO about using `URLSession` and you can read an Apple tutorial on it here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory